# How can I use values in variable explorer as dataframe in Python?

Tags: python

How can I use the values under local_features in dataframe?

I will use the value of local_features in RandomForest. How can I do that? Thanks. Here's the image:

[image: Variable Explorer pane]

Comment: ummm this isnt part of normal python i dont think

Comment: I think you're confusing the variable explorer feature of Spyder with scope of a Python script. What you need to do is create a DataFrame from an array of data. Have a look at the docs for an example: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html